# onEnterframe and Tween in C#

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, c#

I'm trying to write some programs with kinect sdk in c# , I'm a flash developer and my skills are in actionscript  , and I've written some simple projects with c# , the thing I wanna know is that is there a function like onEnterFrame in C# ? or something like tween functions in C# 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WPF/Silverlight, there is the CompositionTarget.Rendering event that essentially does the same thing as Flashes Event.ENTER_FRAME.

For Tweening libraries, I have used Artefact's animator with some success.  I haven't used it extensively, but it worked for the primitive easing that I needed to accomplish.  Site: http://artefactanimator.codeplex.com/